# IE8 on Localhost really slow - Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari all fast on the same - why?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I have some pages on my local machine, accessed via localhost, that are horribly slow to open/load using IE8, but very fast using Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

They used to load really quickly using IE7.

I produced a cut down page to test - to see what was causing the problem - and seriously, the most simple page possible causes it! I.e:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body> 
        Hello!
    </body>
</html>
```

Takes about 15 seconds to open on localhost in IE8, and is instant on all other browsers! Why? What can I do to resolve this?

By the way, tried this on a Web server, connecting via a URL via IE8, and it was basically instant when opened via IE8 via the Web/Web server!

I have Windows Update enabled, so should have the latest of everything.

Note: I only noticed this after my internet connection changed, which was about 2 weeks after IE8 was installed. Possibly that is coincidence, it MAY have started with the install of IE8, I am actually not sure. It is definitely happening now though.

The URL I am using is: http://localhost/fb/starttest.htm

Help!

Comment: Have you tried connecting by IP (EG: http://127.0.0.1/fb/starttest.htm), just to rule out some craziness in resolving "localhost".

Comment: That seems to do it! I.e. 125.0.0.1 works instantly, localhost takes time. So it must be something going on with resolving 'localhost'... a bit odd! But at least now I have a workaround, thank you!

Comment: Interesting, I have the exact same issue with Firefox, but not IE. Page loads instantly in IE, but takes 30 secs on FF (with dependencies), and using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost solves the problem for me, too.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

1- Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

2- Open the file `hosts` using any text editor

3- Add this line to the end of the file

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
```

4- Before you save this file, you need to make sure that any program that access the internet (browsers etc.) is closed - Save the file and test it

Comment: I didn't have to close the browser. I just saved the hosts file and it was MUCH quicker immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Under Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings, is the box "Automatically detect proxy servers" checked?

If so, that does a DNS request to wpad.(domain search suffix) to discover proxy servers via their [Auto Discovery Protocol](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713344.aspx).

If nothing responds, the query will have to timeout before it gives up.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; this setting was NOT ticked. But it works instantly when I use 127.0.0.1, so it seems to be a problem with IE8 attempting to resolve 'localhost'.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this exact same problem recently - 'localhost' taking 15 seconds to load, but 127.0.0.1 loading instantly.

However, I have now fully solved my problem, so I write here in the hope that it will help someone.

My problem coincided with the purchase of a D-Link DIR-655 wireless router, so after trying many of the kindly offered 'fixes' on this forum, I turned back to my router settings in search of an answer.

I eventually discovered a setting on the SETUP - NETWORK SETTINGS page. The 'Enable DNS Relay' box was checked, so I read about it, and it apparently allows the router to lookup DNS addresses from the ISP's server.  This is obviously not desired for a 'local' address on my own PC, and so I tried unticking it.... and HEY PRESTO, IT WORKED!!!

I hope this work for some of you, too!

All the best,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem as you do, except I'm using IE7 (IE takes about 16 seconds to load localhost, while Firefox and Google Chrome loads it in an instant).

I don't have the autodiscovery for proxy checked either.
I also tried starting IE without add-ons (From Accessories->System Tools) and it didn't make a difference.

I found out that using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost greatly improved the speed (like 2 seconds instead of 16 seconds!). However, I edited hosts file and I left only the line

127.0.0.1 localhost

and this didn't fix the problem. Need to dig some further.

Regards,
Nicolae